# Windows Phone 7 equivalent to NSNotificationCenter?

Tags: iphone, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light, message, nsnotificationcenter

I'm new to WP7 and coming from iPhone development. On iPhone I'm used to use NSNotificationCenter to notify my program of something. NSNotificationCenter is build-in the framework out of the box. Is there something similar in WP7? I stumbled uppon MVVM-Light Toolkit but I'm not sure how to use it correctly.

What I want to do:

- Register to an Notification-Id and do something when Notification-Id is received
- Send Notification with Notification-Id and a context (object to pass to observers)
- Everyone who registers to the same Notification-Id will be notified

---

So something like: Registering

```
NotificationCenter.Default.register(receiver, notification-id, delegate);
```

Sending:

```
NotificationCenter.Default.send(notification-id, context);
```

Example for Registering:

```
NotificationCenter.Default.register(this, NotifyEnum.SayHello, m => Console.WriteLine("hello world with context: " + m.Context));
```

Sending ...

```
NotificationCenter.Default.send(NotifyEnum.SayHello, "stackoverflow context");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how to do with the MVVM Light Toolkit:

Registering:

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, NotificationId, m => Console.WriteLine("hello world with context: " + m.Context));
```

Sending:

```
Messenger.Default.Send<string>("My message", NotificationId);
```

Comment: aahh thx. So I have to use my Notification-Id as the Token in registering/sending in MVVM, is that right?

Comment: Exactly. The token can be any type of Object

Comment: Thx, so MVVM is a little way around, i like ... Messenger.Default.Send<Context-Type>(context-object, NotificationId) ... thats why I was a little confused. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Implementing-Push-Notifications-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx you will find a great example on how to use push notification on windows phone 7.

Comment: For what I understand Push notifications are online based right? Or is there an Offline Push Notifications like Local Notifications on iOS for WP7? Because I just need notifications inside my app and don't need an online connection.

Comment: As far as I know is this only for online notifications. I don't know if there is any for offline, but I think not. This would imply multitasking, where your apps would run in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you archive the same result as NSNotificationCenter by creating a singleton which holds a list of observables that implements a specific interface based on your bussiness requirements, or call a lamba, or trigger an event, for each message sent by this singleton you will interate the list of observables and checking the message id, once you find one or more, you can call the interface method, or execute the lambda expression or trigger the event defined to digest the message contents.

Something like below:

```
public class NotificationCenter {

    public static NotificationCenter Default = new NotificationCenter();

    private List<KeyValuePair<string, INotifiable>> consumers;

    private NotificationCenter () {

       consumers = new List<INotifiable>();
    }

    public void Register(string id, INotifiable consumer) {

        consumers.Add(new KeyValuePair(id, consumer));
    }

    public void Send(String id, object data) {

        foreach(KeyValuePair consumer : consumers) {

            if(consumer.Key == id)
                consumer.Value.Notify(data);
        } 
    }
 }

 public interface INotifiable {

    void Notify(object data);
 }


 public class ConsumerPage  : PhoneApplicationPage, INotifiable {

    public ConsumerPage() {

       NotificationCenter.Default.Register("event", this);
    }

    private Notify(object data) {

       //do what you want
    }
 }

 public class OtherPage : PhoneApplicationPage {

    public OtherPage() {

        NotificationCenter.Default.Send("event", "Hello!");
    }
 }
```